# How to invite people who like my facebook posts to like my page in an easy way?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there anyway on how to make people who have liked my post on facebook page to like my page by using graph api or something as going manually takes a lot of time to do that as facebook allows people who have liked your post to be invited to like your page.

Comment: No, that is not possible via API. And btw., just because I might have liked one of your posts, does not mean I want to be pestered with such requests. Use this feature carefully, many users might consider it spam.

Comment: but I can do that one by one.

Comment: Yes, for a certain amount of users. But I am pretty sure Facebook has put limitations on that as well (I’ve seen it in other scenarios like sending friend requests or reporting stuff - after a while you’ll get a message telling you that it looks like you are using that feature to much, and so they’ll give you a timeout, before you can send such requests again.)

Comment: So, combine the features/functionality you are given with a little bit of common sense: Yes,when it comes to inviting users that like your posts regularly or interact with them in ways (f.e. comments) that signal they might be interested in the general page topic - sure, go ahead, and send them requests to like your page. But just firing that in all possible directions ... that is simply spam by the very definition.